# Sign with ethrereumjs-tx and send with HttpProvider gives "Exceeds block gas limit" regardless of gasLimit

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ganache

I'm trying to write a server that holds private keys and signs transactions. I use ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey to generate accounts and private keys, ethereumjs-tx to sign transactions and web3js with a Httprovider to send transactions.

Unfortunately, when I try to send the transaction I always get the error message "Exceeds block gas limit" (even though I set my gasLimit to 21000, well below the block gas limit of my ganache-cli instance).

I suspect the raw encoded transaction is wrongly formed.

Any ideas what the actual problem is and how I can fix it?

Cheers

```
const hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
const Transaction = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const walletHdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";
const hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(process.env.KEYSTORE_SEED));
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

async function generateAccount() {
        const wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(walletHdpath + nextAccountIndex).getWallet();
        nextAccountIndex += 1;
        const addr = '0x' + wallet.getAddress().toString('hex');
        accounts[addr] = wallet;

        await fundAccount(addr);

        return addr;
}

async function fundAccount(address) {
    const txParams = {
        gasPrice: '20000000000',
        gasLimit: '21000',
        from: process.env.KEYSTORE_ADDRESS_0,
        to: address,
        value: web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether'),
        data: ''
      }

      const signed = signTransaction(txParams);

      // this line throws exception: "exceeds block gas limit"
      await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.signed_transaction);
}

function signTransaction(txParams) {
    const from = txParams.from.toLowerCase();
    const wallet = accounts[from];
    if (wallet === undefined) {
        return {sucess: false, message: "unknown from account" }
    } 

    const tx = new Transaction(txParams);
    const pkey = wallet.getPrivateKey();
    tx.sign(pkey);
    const rawTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');

    return { success: true, signed_transaction: rawTx }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with a lower gas price?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the values in the txParams need to be hex encoded and prefixed with 0x